# Kafka Streams DSL: Aggregating a KStream to a GlobalKTable

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have an input stream:

`KStream<String, X> inputStream = ...`

That I would like to operate on (filter then aggregate) in such a way that I output into a `GlobalKTable<String, Y>` which I can then read back in using:

`KeyValueIterator<String, Y> = streams.store("y-global-store", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()).all()`

Can the Streams DSL support this? It seems it would be possible if the output table was a `KTable`, but given the small amount of data I will have in this store I'd like to use a `GlobalKTable`

---

Here is my processor which converts a `KStream<String, X>` to a `KTable<String, Y>`

```
KTable<String, Y> outputTable = inputStream
    .filter(...)
    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), ySerde))
    .aggregate(
        initializeWithNull(),
        aggregateXToAY(),
        Materialized.`as`<String, Y, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>("y-global-store")
            .withKeySerde(stringSerde)
            .withValueSerde(tagRecordSerde)
    )
```

However this doesn't create a `GlobalKTable`, what am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

Stream DSL does not support building GlobalKTable from a KStream. It seems that the only way you could create a GlobalKTable is to using `StreamsBuilder. globalTable("input_topic_for_globalktable")`

I think the reason the DSL does not support create GlobalKtable this way is that each application instance contain the whole GlobalKTable state, so it's disabled logging by default (it does not log changelog to the changelog topic), so it uses an input topic directly for restore state process (fault tolerance), this topic must have log compaction enabled.

One solution is you have to prepare data for this input topic before as output of `outputTable` KTable:

```
outputTable.toStream().to("input_topic_for_globalktable");
```

or directly using the changelog topic of `outputTable` KTable (I think this solution is better since you do not need additional disk space for the new topic), it has the name :

```
<your-application_id>-y-global-store-changelog
```

Comment: Solution 2 sounds like it could work for us as it means we can still do joins on the local `KTable` if required

Comment: Solution 2 sounds perfect but it only works if the changelog topic already exists :(

Comment: yes of course, you have to polute your data to the KTable first, and Ktable is backed by this changelog topic so it can achieve fault tolerance, 2 solution is usable same as each other

Comment: the changelog topic get updated nearly the same time as your KTable, depended on your commit interval and your record cache